# Can't close custom modal that is based on a-modal

Tags: vue.js, antd

I'm building web app Ant Design and Vue, and I created custom modal that is based on `ant-modal`, it is like below.

- My Custom Modal

```
<template>
  <a-modal width="640px" v-bind="$attrs">
    <slot />
  </a-modal>
</template>

:
```

I call it from another component, for example.

```
<template>
  <custom-modal :visible="true" @cancel="handleCancel">
    <a-menu-item>Hi, my custom modal</a-menu-item>
  </custom-modal>
<template>
:

<script>

:

  methods: {
    handleCancel: {
      alert('Now, canceling!');
    }
  }

:
</script>
```

My custom modal is there, but somehow, 'cancelHander' is not called when I click the cancel button on my custom modal.

This is the GIFs of behaviors of my custom component and just plane component(Plain component means `<a-modal>`)

- The GIF for plain component

https://gyazo.com/7407ef4a31a1f9131ddc5f43341f387d

- The GIF for custom component

https://gyazo.com/8e4005f47537ddf4ff431ddbb319efec

And this is the link to my sample code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-antd-template-v03z6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem like below.

- App.vue

```
<template>
:

<custom-modal :visible="true" @cancel="handleCancel">
   <a-modal-item>Custom Modal</a-modal-item>
</custom-modal>

:
</template>
<script>

methods: {
  handleCancel: {
    alert('Do what you want before close modal')
  }
}
:

</script>
```

- CustomModal.vue

```
<template>
  <a-modal v-bind="$attrs" @cancel="handleCancel">
    <slot/>
  </a-modal>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    handleCancel() {
      this.$emit("cancel");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```